# Problems compiling GCC-CilkPlus 4.9

Tags: unix, gcc, makefile, cilk-plus

I am trying to compile, on my x86_64 RHEL machine (CentOS 6.4), the GCC compiler with [Intel CilkPlus](https://www.cilkplus.org/build-gcc-cilkplus) (v4.9) module for compiling applications targeting parallel multicore platforms.

I am following [GNU GCC Doc](http://gcc.gnu.org/install/) for installation which is very very similar for the GCC with CilkPlus extension. I was particularly focused on providing good attention to the [Prerequisites](http://gcc.gnu.org/install/prerequisites.html) and [Configuration](http://gcc.gnu.org/install/configure.html) sections of the before-mentioned doc.

#### 1) Download

I did download everything I needed using [this snapshot](http://gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git;a=commit;h=0b4a2762c0bdd7c567badd7e6e9a302708bd2b21) as specified in the [Instructions page](https://www.cilkplus.org/build-gcc-cilkplus). Download was successful and un-tar as well. I did rename the folder as `cilkplus-gcc` and put it under my `$HOME` directory.

I also created another directory: `$HOME/b-gcc` from where I intend to run the `configure` command and then `make` commands. This will prevent from installing into the same directory (something undesirable for this procedure which encourages building everything on a different directory).

#### 2) Initial configuration

As specified in the documentation, I moved into the `$HOME/cilkplus-gcc/contrib` directory in order to build the three most important libraries needed by the installation process (that is: compiling GCC):

- GMP: located into the `$HOME/cilkplus-gcc/contrib/gmp-4.3.2` directory.
- MPFR: located into the `$HOME/cilkplus-gcc/contrib/mpfr-2.4.2` directory.
- MPC: located into the `$HOME/cilkplus-gcc/contrib/mpc-0.8.1` directory.

I build them in the order of appearance as MPFR depends on GMP and MPC depends on both GMP and MPFR. I wanted to place ll needed files into the `$HOME/cilkplus-gcc` directory so I instructed the installers of these libraries to place everything into the `$HOME/cilkplus-gcc/contrib/tmp` directory. So:

```
sudo $HOME/cilkplus-gcc/contrib/gmp-4.3.2/configure --enable-shared --enable-static --prefix=$HOME/cilkplus-gcc/contrib/tmp
sudo $HOME/cilkplus-gcc/contrib/mpfr-2.4.2/configure --enable-shared --enable-static --prefix=$HOME/cilkplus-gcc/contrib/tmp --with-gmp=$HOME/cilkplus-gcc/contrib/tmp
sudo $HOME/cilkplus-gcc/contrib/mpc-0.8.1/configure --enable-shared --enable-static --prefix=$HOME/cilkplus-gcc/contrib/tmp --with-gmp=$HOME/cilkplus-gcc/contrib/tmp --with-mpfr=$HOME/cilkplus-gcc/contrib/tmp
```

As direct result, my `$HOME/cilkplus-gcc/contrib/tmp` directory is filled with directories `lib`, `include`, `share` and `bin` with those three libs inside.

#### 3) Installation

Time to get busy compiling everything. I move into the `$HOME/b-gcc` directory and from there I issue the following command:

```
sudo $HOME/cilkplus-gcc/configure --prefix=$HOME/cilkplus-install --enable-languages="c,c++" --with-gmp=$HOME/cilkplus-gcc/contrib/tmp/ --with-mpfr=$HOME/cilkplus-gcc/contrib/tmp/ --with-mpc=$HOME/cilkplus-gcc/contrib/tmp/
```

The configuration goes smoothly and creates make stuff into my current folder (`$HOME/b-gcc`). Time to make and I issue: `sudo make`.

Two minutes and I get this error

> g++ -c   -g -DIN_GCC   -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti
>   -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -W -Wall -Wwrite-strings -Wcast-qual  -fno-common  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -Ic-family -I/home/andry/cilkplus-gcc/gcc -I/home/andry/cilkplus-gcc/gcc/c-family -I/home/andry/cilkplus-gcc/gcc/../include -I/home/andry/cilkplus-gcc/gcc/../libcpp/include -I/home/andry/cilkplus-gcc/contrib/tmp//include -I/home/andry/cilkplus-gcc/contrib/tmp//include -I/home/andry/cilkplus-gcc/contrib/tmp//include  -I/home/andry/cilkplus-gcc/gcc/../libdecnumber -I/home/andry/cilkplus-gcc/gcc/../libdecnumber/bid -I../libdecnumber -I/home/andry/cilkplus-gcc/gcc/../libbacktrace    /home/andry/cilkplus-gcc/gcc/c-family/cppspec.c -o
>   c-family/cppspec.o g++   -g -DIN_GCC   -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti
>   -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -W -Wall -Wwrite-strings -Wcast-qual -Wmissing-format-attribute -pedantic -Wno-long-long -Wno-variadic-macros -Wno-overlength-strings -fno-common  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -o cpp gcc.o ggc-none.o \      c-family/cppspec.o driver-i386.o  libcommon-target.a \
>        libcommon.a ../libcpp/libcpp.a  -liconv ../libbacktrace/.libs/libbacktrace.a ../libiberty/libiberty.a
>   ../libdecnumber/libdecnumber.a  /home/andry/b-gcc/./gcc/xgcc
>   -B/home/andry/b-gcc/./gcc/ -dumpspecs > tmp-specs /home/andry/b-gcc/./gcc/xgcc: error while loading shared libraries:
>   libiconv.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or
>   directory make[3](http://gcc.gnu.org/install/prerequisites.html): *** [specs] Error 127 make[3](http://gcc.gnu.org/install/prerequisites.html): Leaving directory
>   `/home/andry/b-gcc/gcc' make[2]: *** [all-stage1-gcc] Error 2
>   make[2]: Leaving directory`/home/andry/b-gcc' make[1](https://www.cilkplus.org/build-gcc-cilkplus): ***
>   [stage1-bubble] Error 2 make[1](https://www.cilkplus.org/build-gcc-cilkplus): Leaving directory
>   `/home/andry/b-gcc'

But I check my `/usr/local/lib` folder and I can clearly see that `libiconv.so.2` is there! So I understand the installation procedure (that is GCC compiling itself) cannot find the library (clearly referenced as I can see the `-liconv` flag). So I delete everything in `$HOME/b-gcc` and issue a modified `configure` command:

```
sudo $HOME/cilkplus-gcc/configure --prefix=$HOME/cilkplus-install --enable-languages="c,c++" --with-gmp=$HOME/cilkplus-gcc/contrib/tmp/ --with-mpfr=$HOME/cilkplus-gcc/contrib/tmp/ --with-mpc=$HOME/cilkplus-gcc/contrib/tmp/ --with-stage1-ldflags=-L/usr/local/lib
```

As I issue `sudo make` again, the previous error is not encountered anymore and time passes. After 5/6 minutes I get this error:

> checking for x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-ar... ar checking for
>   x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-lipo... lipo checking for
>   x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-nm... /home/andry/b-gcc/./gcc/nm checking
>   for x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-ranlib... ranlib checking for
>   x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-strip... strip checking whether ln -s
>   works... yes checking for x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc...
>   /home/andry/b-gcc/./gcc/xgcc -B/home/andry/b-gcc/./gcc/
>   -B/home/andry/cilkplus-install/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/ -B/home/andry/cilkplus-install/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/ -isystem /home/andry/cilkplus-install/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/include
>   -isystem /home/andry/cilkplus-install/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/sys-include
>   checking for suffix of object files... configure: error: in
>   `/home/andry/b-gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/libgcc': configure:
>   error: cannot compute suffix of object files: cannot compile See`
>   config.log' for more details. make[2](http://gcc.gnu.org/install/): ***
>   [configure-stage1-target-libgcc] Error 1 make[2](http://gcc.gnu.org/install/): Leaving directory
>   `/home/andry/b-gcc' make[1]: *** [stage1-bubble] Error 2 make[1]:
>   Leaving directory`/home/andry/b-gcc'

Well, quite a strange stuff... So I checked `$HOME/b-gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/libgcc/config.log` (gonna show the relevant excerpt):

> -isystem /home/andry/cilkplus-install/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/sys-include
>   -c -g -O2  conftest.c >&5 /home/andry/b-gcc/./gcc/cc1: error while loading shared libraries: libmpc.so.2: cannot open shared object file:
>   No such file or directory configure:3593: $? = 1 configure: failed
>   program was: | /* confdefs.h */ | #define PACKAGE_NAME "GNU C Runtime
>   Library" | #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "libgcc" | #define PACKAGE_VERSION
>   "1.0" | #define PACKAGE_STRING "GNU C Runtime Library 1.0" | #define
>   PACKAGE_BUGREPORT "" | #define PACKAGE_URL
>   "http://www.gnu.org/software/libgcc/" | /* end confdefs.h.  */ |  |
>   int | main () | { |  |   ; |   return 0; | } configure:3607: error: in
>   `/home/andry/b-gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/libgcc':
>   configure:3610: error: cannot compute suffix of object files: cannot
>   compile See`config.log' for more details.

Saying that the error is basically the following:

> /home/andry/b-gcc/./gcc/cc1: error while loading shared libraries:
>   libmpc.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

But didn't I already told it (during configure) to go search for `libmpc.so.2` into `$HOME/cilkplus-gcc/contrib/tmp`???

How can I get things done?

How can I get through this? Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

**

I downloaded the snapshot of the cilkplus branch from http://gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git;a=shortlog;h=refs/heads/cilkplus-4_8-branch and click the snapshot link on the top line of the list of checkins. It will take a few moments for the server to fetch the sources and build a compressed tarfile. Once the compressed tarfile has downloaded, unpack it using the following commands after placing it in directory /home  :

```
cd /home
tar -xf gcc-3cfca5e.tar.gz
```

This creates a directory gcc-3cfca5e
Download latest mpfr, mpc and gmp and place these tarballs into the gcc-3fca5e directory.

```
cd /home/gcc-3cfca5e
tar -jxvf mpfr-3.1.2.tar.bz2
tar -xzvf mpc-1.0.1.tar.gz
tar -vxjf gmp-5.1.3.tar.bz2
ln -sf mpfr-3.1.2  mpfr
ln -sf mpc-1.0.1 mpc
ln -sf gmp-5.1.3  gmp

cd /home
mkdir gcc-cilk-obj
mkdir gcc-cilk

cd /home/gcc-cilk-obj

../gcc-3cfca5e/configure  --prefix=/home/gcc-cilk  --disable-multilib  -enable-languages=c

make
make install
```

============
It took about 4 hours to make on a core 2 duo running Slackware current inside VirtualBox 4 
(VBox settings>system>processor> check enable PAE) Windows 7 professional.  My linux system did not have autogen but it worked anyway.